# C++ allocator for objects whose pointers are stored in containers

Tags: c++, memory-management, containers, allocator

I have a `map<int, Foo *>` where I'd need to have many inserts and erases of `Foo *`. Usage would look like

```
    map<int, Foo *> mapping;
    while(  a long time)
    {
        // make new Foo and insert into mapping
        Foo * foo = new Foo( some params)
        mapping.emplace(foo->getID(), foo);

        // sometimes we'd get an existing Foo and remove it
        if ( sometimes)
        {
            int deleteThisID = getIDToDelete();
            Foo * deleteFoo = mapping.find(deleteThisID)->second;
            mapping.erase(deleteThisID);
            delete deleteFoo;
        }
    }
```

I want it to be fast. I suspect the numerous calls to `new` and `delete` would be slow.

A pool allocator seems like a good option. However, my experience with allocators had all been in the context of container of objects (e.g. declare a `map<int, Foo, std::allocator<std::pair<int, Foo>>>`

Which is not relevant.

Should I get a pool allocator, and instead of `new Foo()` and `delete foo`, do `alloc.allocate` and `alloc.destroy`? The new code should not touch `map<int, Foo *>` itself, right?

Comment: "I suspect the numerous calls to new and delete would be slow." Don't write a bunch of sophisticated code based on a suspicion. Benchmark on the systems you expect to deploy to, and write your improvement if the need is demonstrated. (Then you'll be able to benchmark your code as well and measure the improvement.) Note that std::map does a lot of memory allocations/deallocations as well (one per element).

Comment: Why not just use `map<int, Foo>`, or if not that, `map<int, unique_ptr<Foo>>`?

Comment: @Hurkyl - if i use `map<int, Foo>`, doesn't that mean I'd need to create a Foo first and then insert it into the map, which would call the copy constructor. So now I'm creating Foo twice. Isn't that worse?

Comment: @Hurkyl - also, `map<int, unique_ptr<Foo>>` has the same issue as `map<int, Foo*>` at least in terms of needing to find a good and fast way of constructing my Foo objects first, right?

Comment: @user: (re: `map<int, Foo>`) Maybe, maybe not. It would eliminate the dynamic allocations, if those truly are of concern. It may or may not even make it faster to use the map, due to less indirection and a modification to data locality.

Comment: @user: (re: `map<int, unique_ptr<Foo>>`), its performance should ultimately be essentially identical to the raw pointer version, just with fewer chances to mess things up and get memory leaks. (e.g. yours leaks if that `id` is already in the map)

Comment: @user3240688: Using `emplace`, you can avoid the copy, although constructing the correct arguments for map::emplace is a bit annoying, since it often involves using `std::piecewise_construct`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace for examples.

Comment: @rici: Note that with the OP's use case, that would require having some means of predicting a newly created object's id. (or a redesign)

Comment: @hurkyl, yes although it is often the case that the ID is predictable :) What's interesting here is that it seems to be predictable that the ID is not present in the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How `Foo*` is allocated is irrelevant to an instance of `std::map<X, Foo*>`, so you are correct that any change you make to improve the allocation of `Foo`s will be isolated to that problem, and not to `std::map`.

Of course, `std::map` *also* does an allocation for each element (and a consequent deallocation when the element is removed), so you could also consider replacing the allocator used for the `std::map` to attempt to get a performance improvement. That will depend on the performance of the standard library in use, which can only be ascertained through benchmarking.

If your code is as presented and you are always deleting the element removed from the map, you could consider inserting the `Foo` directly into the map instead of using a pointer, which might reduce the number of allocations. Also, if you are using C++11, you might want to consider a smart pointer such as `std::unique_ptr` (or `std::shared_ptr` if you expect the same Foo* to be associated with more than one key.)

Comment: "consider inserting the `Foo` directly into the map instead of using a pointer, which might reduce the number of allocations."   if I follow this route,  I'd create a Foo on the stack before inserting (or emplacing) into the  map. this will call the copy constructor, but if I use a good allocator for the map, at least the memory allocation would be done in a better way than a plain "`new`". The allocator for the map will also take care of destroying Foo. Basically, the win is that I'm creating a temp Foo on the stack and never calling `new` directly. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: @user3240688 Why do you need to create the Foo on the stack? Is it because you cannot predict what the ID will be before the Foo is created?

Comment: If we have a `map<int, Foo>`, how can we insert a `Foo` in there without first creating it on stack? Wouldn't it look like this for a `Foo` with ID of 1?         `map <int, Foo> mapping;  Foo fooOnStack(1);  mapping.emplace(1, fooOnStack);`   (btw the ID is predictable. it is passed into the `Foo` constructor)

Comment: @user3240688: Like this: `mapping.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::make_tuple(1), std::make_tuple(1))`. That may work as follows: construct a new node, then check to see if the key is present in the map; if not, link the new node into the correct place. If the key is present in the map, delete the new node. This will work with a non-copyable non-movable class.